# Inputting text into a text box from a subroutine, VBA

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I am just starting VBA programming. When I try to run the code below, I get an error message, `object needed`.

```
Public Sub TextBox1_Click()
    TextBox1.Text = "Hello World"
End Sub
```

Basically, I am just trying to populate a text box with the words, "Hello World" when the text box is clicked.  I am looking for the most basic way to do this.  I have seen responses to similar questions, and the answers were all over the place.

Comment: Where is the TextBox?  is this code in a sheet, form or module?

Comment: @Mark: you need to specify where the textbox is - for example, is it placed on a form, or embedded in a worksheet? This will affect how we answer.

Comment: You could try `Textbox1.value="Hello World` - but usually *object required* means the compiler can't find the object

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Mark check the name of your TextBox it may not "TextBox1" and Martin's comment is important: what is the location of the textbox?

Answer (score -1):

Try using Textbox focus. Check this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus()

   TextBox1.Text = "Hello World"

End Sub
```

Comment: @KenWhite: i know what object needed error means. I added this coz click event for textbox does not exists so why dont use gotfocus event instead.

Comment: The problem here is the `object needed`, which would refer to the scope in which `TextBox1` is being used. Address the question asked. Using your example in the same scope as the question's would not change anything; if `TextBox1` is not accessible, it's not accessible.